# In WPF trigger DataBinding update from a View class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF app that displays a ListBox of file names in a specified folder and has a button which modifies the file names. I would like the ListBox of filenames to update to reflect this when the button is clicked. From my ViewModel class, I trigger updates by invoking the PropertyChanged event, but I can't figure out how to do the equvalent from the Button_Click method in my View class. Minimal code from the project is below:

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private string[] filesList;
    public string[] FilesList
    {
        get => filesList;
        set
        {
            filesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<ListBox x:Name="FilesInCurrentFolder" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding FilesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ListBox>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
    
    private void AppendDates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dateAppender = new DateAppender(
            Folder.Text,
            FilesInCurrentFolder.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        dateAppender.AppendDates(); 
        // dateAppender.AppendDates() modifies names of files in folder
        // therefore, neet to refresh FilesInCurrentFolder data binding            
    }
```

Can this be done, or am I trying to approach it the wrong way?

Comment: Without a good [mcve], it's not possible to know for sure what the problem is. However, do keep in mind that the value of `FilesList` isn't going to change just because you changed an _element_ of the array. `ObservableCollection<T>` might be a better choice, depending on exactly what's wrong. You might even consider making a list of INPC model objects that themselves don't get replaced, but rather have a "file name" property that gets updated according to whatever your business logic is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a data model e.g. `FileItem` that raises `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` when the `FileItem.FileName` property changes. This will automatically update the items (of type `FileItem`) displayed in the `ListBox`.

**FileItem.cs**

```
class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private string fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get => fileName;
        set
        {
            fileName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private ObservableColection<FileItem> files;
    public ObservableColection<FileItem> Files
    {
        get => files;
        set
        {
            files = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWIndow.xaml**

```
<ListBox x:Name="FilesInCurrentFolder" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FileItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```